# $wpdb query not running

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working on a wpdb query and it's just not running. And for some reason the error reporting for wpdb isn't giving me any errors.

So, can anyone spot an obvious mistake in this query?

I'm attempting to get the `meta_value` of all `_sell_media_attached_file` keys in the `post_meta` table.

I'm first running a `wp_query` , getting the post ID's and then running each post ID through the wpdb query.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
        // run the loop 
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
            'collection' => $club,
            'include_children' => false,
            'year' => $year,
            'monthnum' => $month,
            'day' => $day,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        ) );


        if ( $post_ids = $loop->get_posts() ) {

            $post_ids = implode( ',', $post_ids );

            //breaks here
            $atts_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = $post_ids AND meta_key = '_sell_media_attached_file' " );
            echo('<b>query:</b> <pre>'); var_dump($atts_ids);
```

But as I say, nothing get's output in the `var_dump` and if I add `$wpdb->print_error();` I get no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your piece of code i didn't see the initialization of `wpdb` class to access the `wpdb` class in your wordpress you have to define it as the `global` to access the functions of the class and also if `$post_ids` contains the multiple ids with comma separated you have to use the `IN()` clause instead of `=` operator

```
global $wpdb;

        // run the loop 
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'sell_media_item',
            'collection' => $club,
            'include_children' => false,
            'year' => $year,
            'monthnum' => $month,
            'day' => $day,
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'nopaging'=>true
        ) );


        if ( $post_ids = $loop->get_posts() ) {

            $post_ids = implode( ',', $post_ids );

            //breaks here
            $atts_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id IN($post_ids) AND meta_key = '_sell_media_attached_file' " );
            echo('<b>query:</b> <pre>'); var_dump($atts_ids);
```

Comment: Amazing! Almost perfect. The only issue I can see is that my wp_query is being limited to 12 items. Any idea why?

Comment: Because it take  default limit you have to pass the additional parameter in the array `"nopaging"=>true` to fetch all the posts see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

why not try something like that?

```
if( $loop->have_posts() ){
  $ids = $loop->get_posts();
  foreach( $ids as $id ){
    $atts_ids[] = get_post_meta($id, '_sell_media_attached_file', true|false ); //true if single value false if multiple values return as array
  }
}else{
  //Do something else
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting idea, wouldn't the multiple db queries be a little slow though? The original way does one query and gets everything?